# Windows 7 Delphi5 FormPaint and TopMost not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a program app1 which launches another application using:

```
app2Server := CreateOleObject('app2.Server');
```

1. On ocassion it passes data and control to app2 by calling a procedure app2Server.SendData and then call app2Server.TopMost and sets a variable dataSent = True
2. When the user returns to app1 the Form1.OnPaint event checks if dataSent = True and then retreives some data from app2.

Basically on Windows7 step 2 is not working. It seems to me that two things are not working in Window7 - the app2 OleObject is not being set to TopMost and the app1 Form is not being painted (after the initial creation).

Is this a known issue with Win7 and if so can anyone suggest a way to

1. Set my app2 as TopMost and
2. Get my app1 form to recognise when it's back in in real time.

Thanks alot

Edit: To change the Z-order of the app1 and app2 I use the following:

```
SetWindowPos(Form1.Handle,HWND_BOTTOM,0,0,0,0,swp_NOMOVE or swp_NOSIZE);
app2Server.TopMost;
```

It doesn't appear as if either are working.

ps I inherited this code I just need to make it work :)

Comment: What happens when you set `TopMost`? Is that your code? My guess is that Windows 7 focus stealing prevention is stopping this from working and that you'll find your answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Delphi 5: 1999. Windows 7: 2009. 10 years backward compatibility? I would try playing directly with the Windows API to see if I can get something working...

Comment: @François Should not be a problem. Windows has excellent back-compat.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yea I'm using TopMost and SetWindowPos as described in my edit. It doesn't throw any errors it just doesn't seem to do anything. app2 just flashes in the toolbar. Thanks a lot for the link it seems in right area but I'm not sure how I put his to use in my code? thanks

Comment: `app2server.TopMost` is your code. We cannot tell what it does. If you are seeing an app flashing in the taskbar then yes you have got foreground stealing issues. In order to solve them you need a window that has foreground window setting rights. The link I gave is the best place to start.

Comment: Sorry you're right Server.TopMost is a procedure in my app2 cide which simply contains Form1.TopMost Perhaps this means app2 is not allowed to set itself to foreground. I'll continue to look in to it thoughAllowSetForegroundWindow() doesn't seem to be in my Windows.dcu?

Comment: AllowSetForegroundWindow and LockSetForegroundWindow are missing even in XE2 (so much for compatibility with current OS) but have been in User32 since Win2000 I believe. You have to declare them in your code.

Comment: I notice that some like SetWindowPos and SetForegroundWindow are in Windows.dcu but the ones you mentioned aren't. Do I just have to FindLibrary('user32.dll') and declare the procedure as TAllowSetForegroundWindow? cheers

Comment: It won't work anyway. Windows Vista and above don't let you steal the foreground from the app that already has it without jumping through major hoops. I don't understand why you'd need this anyway; you can post messages back and forth between the two apps instead of playing with foreground focus and topmost/not topmost.

Comment: The two apps are a Membership system and Till. When payment data is passed to the till it would be very beneficial for it to come to the foreground for processing. The Membership system then returning to the foreground is the best trigger to check if the payment has been processed (it actually checks the till for a new receipt number). If you have any alternative suggestions I'd be very grateful

Comment: How long does processing a payment take? I'd think the better way would be for the payment to be processed in the background, and either use a callback function to indicate success or failure to the membership system or post a message to it's window with the same, but I don't have enough info on your app(s) to suggest anything more detailed.

Comment: You can only bring an app to the foreground if you are in control of the app that is currently in the foreground

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have realised that the app2 form1.TopMost call DOES infact bring it to the front but ONLY if it's minimised. If app2 is simply behind app1 during the call it won't come to foreground.
Also the app1 SetWindowsApp(Form1.Handle,HWND_BOTTOM,...) doesn't seem to have an affect on any platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is pretty much this

1. I used a timer within app1 to continually check for payment in app 2 as OnPaint doesn't seem to be working in Win7.
2. Form1.TopMost is infact working on Win7 but only if the application is minimised. Any suggestions welcome.

thanks